# Spring Boot Dashboard won't show me App on VSCode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

I am trying to launch a maven project in visual studio code, I run the mvn clean install command to generate the war and everything is correct, but in the spring-boot dashboard tab the application does not appear to be able to start it.

This is my maven and java version:

```
PS C:\Projects\PortalTimbrado> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T10:06:16-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
Default locale: es_MX, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I have tried with the command ***mvn spring-boot:run*** but failed, this is the output:

````
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from redhat-ga: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from redhat-ga: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from redhat-ga: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (2.5 kB at 1.9 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 9.5 kB/s)
Downloaded from redhat-ga: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (537 B at 368 B/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 14 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.524 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-10T10:41:04-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\dlopezd\.m2\repository), redhat-ga (https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException```


Please help me!
````

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: As mentioned in the error output do you have `No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the c` in your project?

Comment: Review @ToànNguyễnHải's answer.  If that doesn't help, please share your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure have maven build plugin in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also check your parent in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Then retry **mvn spring-boot:run** command

Answer (score 1):

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-spring-boot-dashboard/issues/44

Eskibear commented on 15 Oct 2018

I downloaded your project and had a try, and I just could not reproduce the issue. It first stuck on "importing projects" as expected because the language server was downloading the dependencies. And after <1 min, the project "demo" appeared in the explorer.

You may have a try of the following steps, but I'm not sure whether it can help you out or not.

```
Close all your VSCode windows.
Open ~/.vscode/extensions folder, and remove folders with prefix like "redhat.java", "vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard", "vscjava.vscode-java-debug", "pivotal.vscode-spring-boot".
Open VSCode, install the spring boot dashboard extension from the marketplace.
Now try opening the project again, see if it works.
```